# How do I fetch JSON data from API into ListView?

Tags: android, json, api, listview

since I'm still kinda just starting out on more advanced android development I wanna learn more about APIs and how to fetch JSON data into a ListView.

Let's say I want to be able to search for an actor and in return get all the movies he's been involved with displaying in a listview. I've been glancing at retrofit, but not sure if it does the job I'm looking for.

I'll take any info regarding this matter. Links, snippets, you name it.

Comment: to you who downvoted this, what's the point without any constructive critisicm?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: create activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/actorslist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:color="#ffffff"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:scrollbars="none"
      />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Step 2: create your RequestSenderFiles

-first create one interface AsyncResponse.java

```
public interface AsyncResponse
        {
            void processFinish(Object output) throws JSONException;
        }
```

-Now Create Another File RequestResponse.java

```
public class RequestResponse extends AsyncTask<String ,String,String>
    {

        Activity c;
        public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
        String req="";
        HashMap<String,String> params;
        boolean connect=true;
        int responseCode;
        String url;
        ProgressDialog Loader;
        public RequestResponse(AsyncResponse AsyncResponse, Activity context, String RequestMethod)
        {
            delegate = AsyncResponse;
            c=context;
            req=RequestMethod;
        }
        public RequestResponse(AsyncResponse AsyncResponse, Activity context, String RequestMethod, HashMap<String, String> postparam)
        {
            delegate = AsyncResponse;
            c=context;
            req=RequestMethod;
            params=postparam;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
          // your progressdialog your here
              Loader=new ProgressDialog(c);
                Loader.setMessage("Loading...");
                Loader.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String json="";
            Log.i("REposnse",""+params[0]);
            url=params[0];
            if(req.equals("GET"))
            {
                json=Client(params[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                json=ClientPost(params[0]);
            }
            Log.i("REposnse", "" + json);

            return json;



        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String av)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(av);
            if(connect)
            {
                try
                {
                    delegate.processFinish(av);
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try
                {
                    if ((this.Loader != null) && this.Loader.isShowing())
                    {
                        this.Loader.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                catch (final IllegalArgumentException e)
                {
                    // Handle or log or ignore
                }
                catch (final Exception e)
                {
                    // Handle or log or ignore
                }
                finally
                {
                    this.Loader = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((this.Loader != null) && this.Loader.isShowing())
                    {
                        this.Loader.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                catch (final IllegalArgumentException e)
                {
                    // Handle or log or ignore
                }
                catch (final Exception e)
                {
                    // Handle or log or ignore
                }
                finally
                {
                    this.Loader = null;
                }
                c.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {

                        if(req.equals("GET"))
                        {
                            RequestResponse requestget= RequestResponse(delegate, c);
                            requestget.execute(url);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            RequestResponse requestpost = new RequestResponse(delegate, c, req, params);
                            requestpost.execute(url);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
        public String ClientPost(String url)
        {
            URL url1;
            String response = "";
            try
            {
                url1 = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(1500000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(1500000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(true);
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(params));
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
                Log.i("REposnse",""+responseCode);
                if(responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                {
                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        response+=line;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    connect=false;
                    response="";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                connect=false;

            }

            return response;
        }
        public String Client(String url)
        {
            String result = "";
            try
            {
                URL apiurl =null;
                HttpURLConnection conn;
                String line;
                BufferedReader rd;
                apiurl = new URL(url);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) apiurl.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setReadTimeout(1500000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(1500000);

                responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
                Log.i("REposnse",""+responseCode);
                if(responseCode==HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                {
                    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        result += line;
                    }
                    rd.close();

                }
                else
                {

                    connect=false;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                connect=false;

            }
            return result;
        }
        private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            boolean first = true;
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet())
            {
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    result.append("&");

                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                result.append("=");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }
            Log.i("REposnse",""+params);
            return result.toString();
        }
    }
```

Step 3: create Activity MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
     ListView   list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        try
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main.xml);
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.actorslist);
            request();       
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void request()
    {
     // for POST Request
       //suppose you need to send some data to server to fetch the response from server
      HashMap<String,String> data=new HashMap<String,String>();
      data.put("id","12");
        try
        {
            RequestResponse crr = new RequestResponse(new AsyncResponse()
            {
                @Override
                public void processFinish(Object output) throws JSONException
                {
                    output.toString();//your response
                    // for example you got the response like this
                    String actors = "{"data":[{"actorname":"A"},{"actorname","B"}]}";
                    fetchandapplydata(actors);

                }
            }, this,"POST",data);
            crr.execute(yourserversideurltofetchdata);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }

     // for GET Request
        try
                {
            RequestResponse crr = new RequestResponse(new AsyncResponse()
            {
                @Override
                public void processFinish(Object output) throws JSONException
                {
                     output.toString();//your response
                     // for example you got the response like this
                    String actors = "{"data":[{"actorname":"A"},{"actorname","B"}]}";
                    fetchandapplydata(actors);

                }
            }, this,"GET");
            crr.execute(yourserversideurltofetchdata);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }

     //Depend upon the request method use the code and comment the rest code. 

    }
    public void fetchandapplydata(String data)
    {
        JSONObject object=new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray actors=object.getJSONArray("data");
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> actorsdata=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for(int i=0;i<actors.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject actor=actors.getJSONObject(i);
            HashMap<String,String> actorsnames=new HashMap<String,String>();
            actorsnames.put("name",actor.getString("actorname"));
            actorsdata.add(actorsnames);
        }
        ActorAdapter actoradapter = new ActorAdapter(this, actorsdata);
        list.setAdapter(actoradapter);
    }
}
```

Step 4: Create ActorAdapter.java

```
public class ActorAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    private Activity activity;
    public ActorAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) 
    {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)Ced_activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
    public int getCount()
    {
        return data.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        try
        {
            View vi;
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actor_item, null);
            TextView name= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
            HashMap<String, String> actor = new HashMap<String, String>();
            actor = data.get(position);
            name.setText(actor.get("name"));
            return vi;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Step 5 : create actor_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
        android:id="@+id/name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is step by step process for your question , still if you have any doubt feel free to ask us.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, though I don't doubt that this is a probable solution, it doesn't really help without any further explanation (or atleast some comments). ClientPost is a mess.

Comment: have you tried this code?? clientPOst is used to send the post request.

Comment: mention your errors  we will help you to solve it step by step.